# How to automatically toggle the Dark Reader Chrome plugin?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser, browser-automation, darkmode

###### Question

How can we automatically toggle Dark Mode at predetermined times?

###### Background

Every day, around 5 PM, I switch on the dark mode of the [*Dark Reader* Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dark-reader/eimadpbcbfnmbkopoojfekhnkhdbieeh).
I toggle it off again the next morning to get more bright light in the morning.

As of now, I have remind myself everyday to hit the `<Alt>+<Shift>+<D>`-shortcut that I have configured in Google Chrome (chrome://extensions/shortcuts):
[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Nowadays, toggling can be done through the new dark reader-plugin UI.

### UI-based automation

As of writing, the plugin has 2 types of interfaces.
If you see the following (old) interface, you need to enable the new UI first.
If you see another UI (new), you can skip to the 'Automate the UI' section.

[image: Old interface]

#### Enabling the New Interface

Steps:

1. Click on 'dev tools' (as shown **above**). This will open a small window.
2. Click on 'preview new design' (as shown below). Note that as of writing, the UI of the small window doesn't visually change. Only the label of the button will change. However, when you click on the plugin icon again, you'll see the new UI.

[image: Enable the new interface]

#### Automate the UI

Steps:

1. In the new interface, click on 'settings':

[image: The new interface]

2. Click on 'automation':

[image: Click on automation]

3. Enable the ✔️ checkmark for the active times. In the example below, the browser will turn dark at 17:00 and bright at 05:00.

[image]